# Laravel Chat System RESTful API

Tags: php, laravel, rest, web-services, web

I spend last days searching on how to develop a chat system API to be used later in Mobiles, I searched a lot and there no clear tutorial that gives me the required answer, since I am new on laravel and I can't figure out all the aspects of the laravel and web development, can someone please help me and give me the instruction how to start  and  what notification system do i need to use Pusher or Firebase Clouding Messaging.

Comment: Laravel suggests, for open source, you use `Laravel Echo Server` and for paid (but free-tier) `Pusher`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are familiar with php, here some good link for you :

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database
3. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses (#json-responses)
4. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting (web socket way for "pushing" a notification)
5. for mobile app, maybe you could use Android Studio or with IONIC Cordova

then apart from that, it all depends on your logic, good luck ;)

Comment: I already learned how to develop a RESTful API with laravel but , I have problem with chat system since it's need a special treatment , because it need notification and real time response

Comment: for "realtime" response, you can use web socket ;) or with a classic way, interval on AJAX Request (but it's bad for your server)

Comment: can i use web soket to REST Api ?

Comment: yes, you can, but WS Route will be route for REST Server, and it's different from HTTP server